# CDK exclude files when deploying lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk

Doing some lambdas in typescript and deploying etc via cdk. 
All works fine however I am using:

```
code: lambda.Code.asset('lambdas'),
```

Where the local dir is lambdas. However this deploys the .js, .ts and .d.ts files within and I am wondering if there was anyway to say something like:

```
code: lambda.Code.asset('lambdas/*.js'),
```

And just deploy the javascript files for a smaller deploy etc.

I thought about using the outDir in the tsconfig file but that would also apply to the cdk stack.ts so that won't work.

So any ideas how I can just deploy js files from a ts project?

Comment: Did you try with fromAsset?
code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(".", {include: your_files})

Comment: Isn't that still just a path to a directory (or zip file)? i.e. everything in dir your_files will get deployed (i.e. including all the .ts files)

Comment: You can add "*.js". Can you try and let me know if it works

Comment: nope but what does is:   code: lambda.Code.fromAsset("lambdas",{exclude: ['*.ts']}),     that gets rid of the .d.ts and .ts files (there is no include just exclude)

Answer (score 12):

The key is use `fromAsset` since `asset` is deprecated.
[image]

A bit background about `fromAssest`:

Behind the scenes, CDK uses the [bootstrap stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/tools.html) which creates new Amazon S3.
`fromAssest` Loads the function code from a local disk asset, the directory will be zip archived and then uploaded to bootstrap S3 bucket, then the exact location of the S3 objects will be passed when the stack is deployed.

In order to exclude files use [`AssetOptions`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-s3-assets.AssetOptions.html) - `exclude`. [fix(assets): support exceptions to exclude patterns #4473.](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/4473)

[image]

**Usage:**

```js
    code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(".", {exclude: ['*.ts']})
```